# UIView transition inside uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, animation

Please help!

I have a `UITableviewcell` with a button in it. When i click the button i want a `UIView` which has 3 buttons (which is hidden outside to screen bound's width on screen's right side) to slide in on top of the old view.And when user clicks on one of the buttons in new view it should slide back to its old position. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What i have tried so far is

```
let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,0)
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
    newview.transform = offScreenLeft
} , completion:{})
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: And what is your problem/question?

Comment: My problem is I want to slide in a view which is hidden in the right side of a table view cell when user clicks on a button in the cell. @HermannKlecker

Comment: Well, I don't see a reason for using a Transformation here. if it is just about sliding it in then you could set its frame and animate it. So is your question realted to the animation/sliding as such or is it related to how to interact with the button in your cell. Splease be specific about the problem.

Comment: Yes, i want to animate the frame inside an UITableViewCell. My question is not regarding interaction with button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to use `CGAffineTransformation`, set the starting state before the animation, and the target state in the animation block.
Should be like this

```
newView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 0)
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
    newView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
})
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkHim, I will try this.

Comment: Mark, thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer. And one more issue now. I wanted the view to slide in from right side of the table cell, so when i changed the "-" sign  ie. when used CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 0)  i could accomplish that. But when i tried to send the slided view back to its original position, animation is not working. Can you help me with this.

Comment: Happy to help, I suggest you start a new question where you show your current code for the animation back. Comments are not really good for that. Post a reference to the new question here and i will gladly try to help you

Comment: Hi Mark, I have posted a new question and the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370775/uiview-transition-in-table-view. Hope I have described it well.